# How to detect an empty tag in xml document using jdom

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom, jdom-2

I'm using JDOM to parse an xml document that could be like this:

```
<person>
  <name id="blah"> xyz </name>
  <friends />
</person>
```

I'm trying to find out what the correct way to detect an empty tag such as `<friends />` or `<friends></friends>`

would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `Element` for the `<friends>` tag and for an empty element the `getChildren()` method should return an empty list.

Comment: Thanks Jim. But when there is a non-empty element without any children such as below, the test fails.
`<person>
  <name id="blah"> xyz </name>
  <friends> list of friends </friends>
</person>`

Comment: Where is the "empty element" in that?  I don't understand.  Do you mean to say the `<friends>` tag is empty because it contains only text and not other tags?  In that case you must examine the contained element(s) to distinguish between text and other tags.

Comment: Please put all this clarification into the original question, not in comments.  When the question is clear I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ykw, you're right. The example in my comment doesn't qualify as an empty element.